# How to group dates into weeks?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following table:

[image: My current table view at Access]

I somehow managed to write a query which allowed me to sum and group the total of visitors to a zoo per day (as the table), but I need to group even further into weeks in order to calculate the percentage of growth of the amount of visitors week over week for the last four weeks of the data.

How can I do that in Access SQL?

This is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 35 date_info.calendar_date, Sum(restaurants_visitors.reserve_visitors) AS SUMreserve_visitors
FROM date_info INNER JOIN restaurants_visitors ON date_info.calendar_date = restaurants_visitors.visit_date
GROUP BY date_info.calendar_date
ORDER BY date_info.calendar_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Access stores dates as a floating point number whose integer part represents days since 1900 and whose fractional part is the time expressed as a fraction of a day. If I divide the date by 7 and truncate to integer I will have a week number spanning Saturday to Friday.  Put that in a Group By and you're good to go.

```
Group By Fix(date_info.calendar_date/7)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a function to calculate the week number. Also the year of the week numbers, as weeks can span New Year.

This you can format like `2021W23` to list orderly:

```vb
' Returns, for a date value, a formatted string expression with
' year and weeknumber according to ISO-8601.
' Optionally, a W is used as separator between the year and week parts.
'
' Typical usage:
'
'   FormatWeekIso8601(Date)
'   ->  2017-23
'
'   FormatWeekIso8601(Date, True)
'   ->  2017W23
'
' 2017-04-28. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function FormatWeekIso8601( _
    ByVal Expression As Variant, _
    Optional ByVal WSeparator As Boolean) _
    As String
    
    Const Iso8601Separator  As String = "W"
    Const NeutralSeparator  As String = "-"
    
    Dim Result              As String
    
    Dim IsoYear As Integer
    Dim IsoWeek As Integer
    
    If IsDate(Expression) Then
        IsoWeek = Week(DateValue(Expression), IsoYear)
        Result = _
            VBA.Format(IsoYear, String(3, "0")) & _
            IIf(WSeparator, Iso8601Separator, NeutralSeparator) & _
            VBA.Format(IsoWeek, String(2, "0"))
    End If
    
    FormatWeekIso8601 = Result

End Function


' Returns the ISO 8601 week of a date.
' The related ISO year is returned by ref.
'
' 2016-01-06. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Week( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    Optional ByRef IsoYear As Integer) _
    As Integer

    Const MaxMonthValue          As Integer = 12
    Const MinMonthValue          As Integer = 1
    Const MaxWeekValue           As Integer = 53
    Const MinWeekValue           As Integer = 1

    Dim Month       As Integer
    Dim Interval    As String
    Dim Result      As Integer
    
    Interval = "ww"
    
    Month = VBA.Month(Date1)
    ' Initially, set the ISO year to the calendar year.
    IsoYear = VBA.Year(Date1)
    
    Result = DatePart(Interval, Date1, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
    If Result = MaxWeekValue Then
        If DatePart(Interval, DateAdd(Interval, 1, Date1), vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) = MinWeekValue Then
            ' OK. The next week is the first week of the following year.
        Else
            ' This is really the first week of the next ISO year.
            ' Correct for DatePart bug.
            Result = MinWeekValue
        End If
    End If
        
    ' Adjust year where week number belongs to next or previous year.
    If Month = MinMonthValue Then
        If Result >= MaxWeekValue - 1 Then
            ' This is an early date of January belonging to the last week of the previous ISO year.
            IsoYear = IsoYear - 1
        End If
    ElseIf Month = MaxMonthValue Then
        If Result = MinWeekValue Then
            ' This is a late date of December belonging to the first week of the next ISO year.
            IsoYear = IsoYear + 1
        End If
    End If
    
    ' IsoYear is returned by reference.
    Week = Result
        
End Function
```

Now you can create a query like this to list the visitor counts from the last week and four weeks back:

```sql
SELECT 
    FormatWeekIso8601(date_info.calendar_date) As Year_Week, 
    Sum(restaurants_visitors.reserve_visitors) AS SUMreserve_visitors
FROM 
    date_info 
INNER JOIN 
    restaurants_visitors 
    ON date_info.calendar_date = restaurants_visitors.visit_date
GROUP BY 
    FormatWeekIso8601(date_info.calendar_date)
HAVING
    FormatWeekIso8601(date_info.calendar_date) Between 
        FormatWeekIso8601(DateAdd("ww", -4, date_info.calendar_date)) And
        FormatWeekIso8601(DateAdd("ww", -1, date_info.calendar_date))
ORDER BY 
    FormatWeekIso8601(date_info.calendar_date) DESC;
```

Source: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date)